# Laravel i need validate field to check GPX or CSV files

Tags: php, laravel, validation, web

i need validate rule that will not block GPX/CSV files, and will block other files.
i've tried mimes and mimetypes, and some combinations with the names of the files(gpx,.gpx,GPX,.GPX and the same for csv). My problem is what these combinations blocking all files including GPS/CSV.

Here is the example of my code:

```
'file' => ['required','file','mimes:jpg,csv']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
'file' => ['required','file','mimetypes:text/csv,text/plain,application/xml,application/gpx+xml']
```

or

```
'file' => ['required','file','mimes:csv,txt,xml,gpx']
```

Comment: didn't helped to me, program still blocking my files(

Comment: what is your file size?!

Comment: minimum size is 1.81 megabyte

Comment: can you test a file less than 1.4 mb ?!

Comment: tried file 4 kilobyte, program still blocking

Comment: can you remove 'file' and test?

Comment: tried - same result

Comment: let me install new Laravel and test... and update...

Comment: i've found solution - "mimes:csv,txt,xml", ty for the help

Comment: ok, thanks also, i updated answer for mimetypes also, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Found working solution on laravel 8 `mimes:csv,txt,xml`